# Is there a ruby function to do !(val).nil??

Tags: ruby

I frequently find myself doing this:

```
!(val).nil?
```

My code would be prettier if there was a method like

```
val.exists?
```

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use the `unless` statement, eg,

```
do_something unless val.nil?
```

which is probably pretty close to the ideal way to phrase it: if you had a `non_nil?` method you'd have a negated statement instead of a positive statement like this one.

Answer (score 6):

```
if !val.nil?
  # do something
end

# is equivalent to

if val
  # do something
end
```

If you are using Rails, ActiveSupport provides [two Object extensions](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb) called Object#blank? and Object#present?.

```
if !address.nil? && !address.empty?
# becomes
if !address.blank?
# which becomes
if address.present?
```

Comment: this won't work if `val` is a boolean - `false` will mistakenly be treated the same as `nil`.

Comment: It's unlikely he's testing a (possible) Boolean for nil, since you don't do anything but check the truth value anyway.

Comment: @klochner I coldn't say better. Peter's comment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: let's say `val` is a flag that indicates whether something is true or false. before checking some condition, `val` will be `nil`, but after checking the condition, `val` becomes `true` or `false`. this is the 'unlikely' case that `val` is `nil` before becoming `true` or `false`.

Comment: I'll grant that it's possible, just unlikely.  More likely he's trying to avoid an exception when subsequently calling val.foo or val["foo"]

Comment: Peter, I know that it's possible but that sounds a bad design to me. If you have a variable `condition` supposed to be a boolean flag, you should either initialize it or thread it as boolean.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that !val.nil? is a code smell indicating that there might be a better way to do what you're trying to do; perhaps the code is relying on a datastructure which could be replaced by something which could handle the edge cases better.

Here's an example of one way `.nil?` might be being used poorly:

For instance:

```
blah = {}
[:a,:b,:c,:a].each do |l|
     if blah[l].nil?
         blah[l] = 0
     else
         blah[l] += 1
     end
end
blah #=> {:a => 2, :b => 1, :c =>1}
```

Could potentially be rewritten as

```
blah = Hash.new(0)
[:a,:b,:c,:a].each{|i| blah[i] += 1} #or with inject.
```

The `||=` operator is another area to look into.

---

**REDACTED:**
A common idiom for doing something with a value which could be nil is using the && operator, since nil is falsy, so instead of

```
if !val.nil?
   val.do_something
end
```

It's common to just write

```
val && val.do_something # =>nil if val is nil, val.do_something's value otherwise
```

*This requires just as much knowledge about the way nil is handled in boolean expressions as is required for mckeed's (x if y) conditional example below, so it doesn't really help the code read better.*

Comment: Using the `&&` like that is more of a python idiom. I think it is way less readable than `val.do_something if val` or with ActiveSupport, `val.try &:do_something`

Comment: I agree, but I'd also say that:
`blah = val.do_something if val` is confusing if you don't realize there's an implicit `else nil` there. So your example is good, but looks strange if the return value of `val.do_something` is what's desired.
I think the code smell is the biggest issue here, I'll edit my answer to highlight it better.

Comment: I guess `blah = val && val.do_something` isn't much better either if you don't know the idiom. I've just been using it for a while now, so I read it as "this could get nil".

Answer (score 1):

!!val

Comment: +1 though this might be harder for readability, but I really hope it becomes an idiom.

Comment: This does not work, as !!false is false, this is different than !false.nil?

Answer (score 0):

```
module Nonnil
  def non_nil?
    !(self.nil?)
  end
end

class Someclass
  include Nonnil
  extend Nonnil
end
```

This will add the member `.non_nil?` to the class `Someclass`, defined as the inverse of `.nil?`.  Mix this module into the class that 'val' (in your example) belongs to and you will have a handy shortcut.  Mix this into class `Object` and it will be available for every class (since `Object` is the parent of all classes).